# Create Jar file using maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm having some issues while making the JAR file which project type is pom and adding this jar in other project as dependency.

I'm using maven shaded plugins to make a JAR . It compiles well but it creates a jar file in project target directory but not in .m2 folder. Moreover, when i extract the file it doesn't have classes and resources etc

**here are two projects i have**

**1) ProjectTestB**
Project B is a independent project which have various modules like scheduler, service, web module which adds as dependency in other project

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestProjectB</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectTestB</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                  <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                  <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
    <modules>
        <module>scheduler</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**2) ProjectA**

Project A contains a dependency of ProjectB and some other services and business classes. Only Project A  Contains Main class which will create executable JAR file

```
Pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>TestProjectB</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectTestB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

**So the questions are**

1) How to make jar which have all the classes, resources etc if project package is POM (Project B)?

2) How can i add Project B jar file in Project A class path to access it modules?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you try do something strange.

Your `projectB` has many modules, so your `projectA` should has dependency to those modules. Propably module of `projecB` has type `jar`, so you can ease depend on it without doing magic with `projectB`